# DownloadString when "UseDefaultCredential = True" has been set gives 401 error

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, webclient, downloadstring

I have deployed a website to IIS (as always works fine on local machine) and have found that when I run one of my routines it fails with a 401 not authorised error:

Code is as follows:

```
          string html = String.Empty;
            string CurrentURL = Request.Url.Scheme + Uri.SchemeDelimiter + Request.Url.Host + Request.Url.PathAndQuery;
            Byte[] sAttachment;

            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {                    
                client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

                _logger.Debug("Getting page content ready to fax...");
--> fails here: html = client.DownloadString(new Uri(CurrentURL));

                html = html.Replace("Add Recipient", "");
                html = html.Replace("Send Fax", "");
                html = html.Replace("Close", "");

                //make sure the destination fax number and recipient is in the html
                string toFaxDetailsHTML = "insertFaxDetails\">";
                toFaxDetailsHTML += "<label class=\"form-label col-md-2 text-right\">Fax: </label>" + FVM.ToFaxNumber + "<br/>";
                toFaxDetailsHTML += "<label class=\"form-label col-md-2 text-right\">To: </label>" + FVM.ToName + "<br/><br/>";
                html = html.Replace("insertFaxDetails\">", toFaxDetailsHTML);

                sAttachment = FVM.PdfSharpConvert(html);
                FVM.Attachment = sAttachment;
            }
```

Any help appreciated.

Environment is IIS 7 on Windows 2008 R2 standard. 
Using MVC 5 c# .NET 4.5.2

Comment: If you're trying to get the rendered content of a controller action from within another action (e.g. the GET version of the same URL) in order to turn it into a PDF, then there may be more efficient ways to go without doing a web request to yourself (where you're at the mercy of host names, outgoing internet access, web proxies etc). Some emailing actions do a similar thing - suggest you start by Googling there, for example http://www.codemag.com/article/1312081

Comment: Top! Thanks @Reddog

Comment: @Reddog - I have used the approach described in the article you have linked above - worked first time ... (what's wrong??) :-) - thanks for your input!

Comment: that's great news! I haven't tried that specific approach in the article so I can't vouch for it, so it'll be worth doing research if there are better ways.

Answer (score 0):

IIS creates a user named "IUSR",to access files via IIS as defaut user. So it is improtant that "IUSR" has proper access rights to to files/folders.

So please follow the next steps to see if IUSR has proper access rights:

```
Deploy Folder→Right Click→Properties→Security Tab
```

Please make sure that IUSR is in Group or user names list, If No, please do the following:

```
Click Edit→Add→Advanced→Find→Add IUSR.
```

※I am using a Japanese version of Widows, so button names may be slightly off

Comment: IUSR has full control of folders.

Comment: @WeePecky each and every sub folder in the "deployment folder", NOT "development", which may have files that you request?

Comment: Yes, all folders have all permissions selected for IUSR on the webserver file system.